# Tem como adicionar touch events no jquery Cycle?

Tags: jquery

Queria saber se tem como adicionar eventos de toque no jquery cycle. Porque eu quero colocar eventos de toque no meu slideshow.

Código:

```html
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script src="js/slide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slides">

    <div class="slide-1">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
     <div class="info-slide-left">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a>  
       <div class="seta-direita">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
        
         
     </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="slide-2">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"><a/>
     <div class="info-slide-rigth">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a>
       <div class="seta-direita-2">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
       
       
       </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide-3">
    
     <a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"></a>
     <div class="info-slide-right-3">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a> 
       <div class="seta-direita-3">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
        
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="slide"><!--Grupo 2 de slide-->

    <div class="slide-1">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
     <div class="info-slide-left">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a>  
       <div class="seta-direita">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
        
         
     </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="slide-2">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"><a/>
     <div class="info-slide-rigth">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a>
       <div class="seta-direita-2">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
       
       
       </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide-3">
    
     <a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"></a>
     <div class="info-slide-right-3">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a> 
       <div class="seta-direita-3">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
        
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  

  </div><!--Fim do 2 Slide-->
</div><!--Fim da div slideshow-->
```

Código Jquery Cycle:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.slideshow').cycle({
      timeout:4000,
   speed:600,
   fx:'scrollHorz',
   next: '#btn-prev',
   prev: '#btn-next'
   });
});
```

Comment: Coloca o código aí do Cycle.

Comment: Tá vou colocar abaixo da pergunta !!

Comment: @DiegoSouza já coloquei o código.

Comment: Você quer tipo que passar de um slider para o outro com o dedo arrastando ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza Sim esse tipo mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Então, aqui nessa tag: `<div class="slideshow">`

Você faz assim:

```
<div class="slideshow" 
    data-cycle-swipe="true"
    data-cycle-swipe-fx="scrollHorz">
```

Adiciona esses outros dois atributos.

Comment: O meu slider é o jquey cycle 1 não o 2.

Comment: Então terá que usar uma biblioteca alternativa. Sugiro o Hammer Js.

Comment: É facil usar o Hammer ? Pq eu sou muito ruim em javascript.

Comment: Nesse caso vai ser um pouco chato de fazer. Você não pode atualizar para o Cycle 2 ?

Comment: Já tentei o cycle 2, mas, não funcionou no meu slideshow.